# Google IO Slides Template - Javascript on each slide

Tags: javascript

this my first question! I am playing around with the Google slide template that was used for the Google IO presentations this year (2011).

http://code.google.com/p/io-2011-slides/

What I would like to do is run Javascript on a per slide basis. This is code from another SlideShow library that I would like to recreate using the Google IO template:

```
//You can trigger Javascript based on the slide number like this:
$('html').bind('slide', function(e, id) { 
  switch(id) {
    case 2:
      console.log('This is the second slide.');;
      break;
    case 3:
      console.log('Hello, third slide.');
      break;
  }
});
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do something similar with the Google IO slide framework? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the slide definition, you can include code.

```
<article onslideenter="console.log('This is the second slide.');">
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: It did work for me. Here's whole paste of the slide deck with the sample code that worked for me http://pastebin.com/5DGG9rG6 in case it helps to see in context

Comment: Yes! It does work, I am sorry. I was using an older version of the slide.js code. Thanks so much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [slides code](http://io-2011-slides.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/slides.js), I noticed that it emits events `slideenter` and `slideleave`. So Bemmu's solution should work. You might also be able to do `article.addEventListener('slideenter', function(){...}, false)` or (`.attachEvent` for IE)