# Event when slide is displayed in ioslides?

Tags: r-markdown

Is there an event triggered when there's a page change in an ioslides presentation?  I'd like to allocate some resources to display the slide, and release them when the user moves on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ioslides triggers `slideenter` and `slideleave` events on each slide.  These are currently handled as strings, so you'd use Javascript like

```
slide.setAttribute("slideenter", "somecode();");
```

to execute `somecode();` when the slide is entered.  See also this answer:  [Google IO Slides Template - Javascript on each slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982851/google-io-slides-template-javascript-on-each-slide)